# Setup Factory 9: How i can fix Unknown Publisher name?

Tags: c#, installation

I am using Setup Factory 9 for create my application 's **setup.exe**.
But on the end user 's computer, the exe is notify as virus with below screen.
How I can release my application?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The suggestion is to use a different tool, or to sign your setup with a digital certificate ([latter must be done to get Publisher name correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51209972/129130)), but first some notes on "SmartScreen". You will see that "*trust can be bought*" via a fancy certificate ([EV code-signing certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate)). Interesting concept... See first, bolded link below.

---

***SmartScreen***: Window's SmartScreen feature confuses many people, including me. It is a "trust based" thing where you need to make sure your setup is a "known setup" that has "good reputation". I have these old links for you, but can't really tell you that much about it:

- **[How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018)** (recommended)
- [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer)
- [How to pass the Windows Defender SmartScreen Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806909/how-to-pass-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-protection)
- [How to avoid the "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-fro/48947981#48947981)

---

***MSI Package***: I think you might have an easier time of it if you package in more common formats. [MSI would be ideal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624070/how-to-create-windows-installer/49632260#49632260). Certain binary formats and packaging formats are renown as vessels for malware (whether deserved or not). The great tool [VbsEdit](http://www.vbsedit.com/) - for example - which allows you to compile an executable for a VBScript - often has these binaries flagged as malware. Not to criticize this tool (it is great - especially the [sample gallery](http://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/default.asp)), but that was the first example of "*poor trust for binaries*" that came to mind. "*Script kiddies*" ruin the reputation of an otherwise good product?

- [**List of Deployment Tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130)
- [**WiX Quick Start Tips**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

WiX is the free option (open source). Great, but with a learning curve (see links above). The other tools are great but commercial (costs money).