# "Proper" way of releasing software and creating an installer for it

Tags: windows-installer, installation, release, smartscreen

Let's suppose I've just created an app in visual studio and now I want to distribute it. I've set the app to release mode and I have a copy of the app that works just fine. My main question is how would I go about creating an installer for it and making sure Windows knows it's trustworthy? Do I have to create some sort of certificate?

I've been searching and downloaded NSIS but I'm not sure how to use it so I just used Inno Setup Compiler which works just fine. Sometimes Avast checks my application and takes about 5 or 10 seconds before opening it but that doesn't happen with other applications.

Is that a problem with avast?

Comment: I guess I should read better, is it the setup that takes long to launch? Or is it the application that takes long to launch? Is this a C++ application? Or a managed application? (C# and associates)? What happens if you turn off Avast? (maybe that is what you did?).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I did: disabled avast from running. It's a .net app that doesn't contain any malicious code. Windows on itself lets me run the app just fine (doesn't show me windows protected your pc dialog)

Comment: If you can, maybe try with a different anti-virus to see if the behavior is consistent? You could also talk to the Avast guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Deployment Tool***: [Here is a piece on common MSI tools, and links to other, non-MSI deployment tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840). The links to Stefan Kruger's site [installsite.org](https://www.installsite.org) shows the full list of available tools for [**`MSI`**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm) and [**`non-MSI`**](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/tt_nonmsi.htm). The most common tools are: [**`WiX`**](https://www.wixtoolset.org) (open source, [learning curve - hints here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)), [**`Advanced Installer`**](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) (great tool, lots of smarts), [**`Installshield`**](http://www.installshield.com) (market leader), and others. Have a look.

***SmartScreen***: Windows now features "SmartScreen" - which is a trust based system where your binaries have to "earn reputation" through use. Essentially you need to buy a **`Extended Validation Certificate`** to "buy trust" outright (Interesting concept... Who smells a racket?):

- **[How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018)** (About the certificate: [EV code-signing certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate))
- [How to pass the Windows Defender SmartScreen Protection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48806909/how-to-pass-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-protection)

[***VirusTotal.com***](https://www.virustotal.com): I like to upload my binaries to [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com). They check the binaries with a plethora of malware scanners and you can see if any scanners flag your binaries as suspicious. An important step to check both for **genuine malware** in your release files (happens), and also - and just as importantly - for **false positives** - that would otherwise cause your users problems and you a lot of support calls.

***Reputation***: Note that I am not sure whether uploading helps with the binaries reputation for SmartScreen. I don't think it does - at least not in a quick way. You need an [**`EV code-signing certificate`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) to "buy trust" for large scale distributions. I should add that the vetting and approval for such certificates involve verifying the company's existence (like normal certificates), but also dongles or hardware keys - I think - and hence is quite a bit of fuss to get, and hence does "prove" that the distributor must at least be well-organized.

---

***Links***:

- [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer)
- [How to avoid the "Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting warning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946680/how-to-avoid-the-windows-defender-smartscreen-prevented-an-unrecognized-app-fro)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll check that out!

Comment: Yep, so I've made an installer with Inno Setup Compiler because I couldn't find any good beginner tutorials for NSIS. Should I keep using it or should I switch to NSIS? My main problem is that I can't find any tutorials to do stuff. InstallShield is paid I believe so it's not really an option for me :/

Comment: I don't use either tool much. Commercial tool [Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com) has some free features. And there is always [WiX - open source and free, but with a learning curve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130) (samples in there - linked). And, again: [here is an ad-hoc list of MSI tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50229840/129130) (with more links to other tools).

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll check it out when possible! :)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has some requirements for getting your app certified. You can read about them in the links I posted below. As for Avast, I'm not too sure what it could be, try using another anti virus program to see if it's taking a while to virus scan. It could also be a performance issue but that's unlikely. 
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/win_cert/windows-certification-portal)
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/win_cert/certification-requirements-for-windows-desktop-apps)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, it seems rather complicated though