# How do get the publisher name to display in the ClickOnce installer dialog box

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installation, clickonce

In Visual Studio 2015, how can I get the ClickOnce installer dialog box to display the name of the publisher as indicated in the image?

[image]

I tried entering the name into `Project Properties -> Publish -> Options -> Description -> Publisher Name`, but that only adds the name to the folder on the Start Menu after it's installed.

The Company field under `Project Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information` didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***MSIX***: Maybe consider having [a quick read about MSIX](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-introduction.html) - a new universal package format designed for Windows 10 apps.

---

***ClickOnce***: Though I don't use [ClickOnce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce), I believe the problem you see is due to a [missing certificate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/42c6138a-550b-4858-9f66-2165ef375452/how-to-change-product-name-and-publisher-seen-during-installation-of-application?forum=winformssetup). You need an **Authenticode code signing certificate** to sign your setup: [**ClickOnce and Authenticode**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-and-authenticode?view=vs-2019).

***Extract***: In the document linked above, it says:

"*You can obtain a certificate for code signing in one of three ways:*

1. *Purchase one from a certificate vendor.*
2. *Receive one from a group in your organization responsible for creating digital certificates.*
3. *Generate your own certificate by using the New-SelfSignedCertificate PowerShell cmdlet, or by using MakeCert.exe, which is included with the Windows Software Development Kit (SDK).*

You need to use **`option 1`** for **general deployment**. **`Option 2`** is for **company use**, and **`option 3`** is basically for **testing**.

> ***Summary***: With option 1 you should get the right **`Publisher`** name displayed. So obtain a proper code signing certificate from an issuing authority to correct the problem you see. Obviously first check if your company already has such a certificate (very frequently they do these days).
>
> ***SmartScreen***: Here is an answer on SmartScreen and digital certificates using MSI. Please skim: [How to add publisher in Installshield 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50407893/how-to-add-publisher-in-installshield-2018)

---

***Links***:

- [ClickOnce security and deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment)
- ["Proper" way of releasing software and creating an installer for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56544578/propper-way-of-releasing-software-and-creating-an-installer-for-it/56549233#56549233)

Comment: I suspected this might be the problem, but I wasn't sure. I actually do have a certificate on the manifest, but I don't know if it contains the company name. I'll talk to the guy who acquired it for us. Thanks.